# Can someone connect to my OpenVPN server without the keys in configuration file?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've recently setup a OpenVPN server on my VPS, and I want to expose the VPN server port to the internet. I've installed it using the following script: https://git.io/vpn (a installer). The main point which I'm asking just to be sure is, if I expose the port which the OpenVPN server is running on (1194) to the internet, can someone connect without the keys in the configuration files ? And if not, is it secure how I have it? The configuration file has the following entries in it (they may be important to this question):

> auth SHA512

and:

> cipher RC2-CBC

then it contains some keys like: **certificate key**, **private key**, **OpenVPN Static Key V1**

You can find the full configuration here: https://pastebin.com/AUKt1Ve8 (posted on pastebin because stackoverflow removes the lines)

I'm new to OpenVPN, so all help is appreciated! Thanks,

Best Regards - Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are safe. Only people you assigned a certificate for are able to connect to the VPN.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. Basically I have a server but I want to first connect to the VPN, then from the VPN to sshd on my server. So it's safe now, noone should be able to bruteforce it or anything, right?

Comment: @MatoSustak that is true, you are safe. But it would be much faster and easier to just set up ssh to authenticate with a pair of keys and disable password auth.

Comment: Thank you, the destination server is pretty secure, but just in case. :D